# Adding a TextWatcher to EditText inside ActionBarSherlock having MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS

Tags: android, android-edittext, actionbarsherlock, menuitem, textwatcher

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, I want to display an EditText in it with MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS. It takes the full width of the bar and shows as desired. But I am running into trouble trying to add a TextWatcher to it.

So based on the accepted answer here: http://goo.gl/ite6h I write:

```
    EditText search;
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0, 1, 1, R.string.inlineSearch).setIcon(R.drawable.action_search).setActionView(search).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.e("TextWatcher","after");
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Log.e("TextWatcher","before");
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.e("TextWatcher","onText");
    }

}; 

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        Log.e("onOptions",""+item.getItemId()); // Line 150
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                search = (EditText) item.getActionView();
                search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
                search.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        }  
        return true;
    }
```

Problem is, line 150 is never reached (no log) and nothing the listener is not added to the search (EditText).

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI,

This worked for me, gives me the EditText across the whole width of the ActionBar (which I couldn't seem to do without a RelativeLayout, even if using MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS) and call its TextWatcher methods:

```
EditText search;
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout rl =(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_text, null);
    search=(EditText)rl.getChildAt(0);
    search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, R.string.inlineSearch).setIcon(R.drawable.action_search).setActionView(rl).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Log.e("TextWatcher","after");
    }

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    Log.e("TextWatcher","before");
    }

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    Log.e("TextWatcher","onText");
    }

    };
```

& my layout/search_text:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
          >
    <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/search_text"
              style="@style/EditTextHoloDark"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
              android:imeActionId="1337"
              android:imeOptions="actionDone"
              android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:hint="Search"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/action_search"

              />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for "EditTextHoloDark" theme -`@style/EditTextHoloDark`